# Opening and closing vue-ctk-date-time-picker using a button click in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datetime, npm

I am using the component - https://github.com/chronotruck/vue-ctk-date-time-picker in my component. The issue that I am facing is that i want to keep the component as it is but somewhere in my component a button should be able to open and close it, It seems like the component does not offer any such functionality, can anyone please help with the same.

Code sandbox - [Sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-saha-m85sdg?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

What I am doing -

```
 <template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <vue-ctk-date-time-picker
      v-model="theDate"
      :name="'Date'"
      :format="'YYYY-MM-DD'"
      :formatted="'DD MMM, YYYY'"
      :only-date="true"
      :data-vv-as="'date'"
      :first-day-of-week="1"
      :range="true"
    >
    </vue-ctk-date-time-picker>
    <button>Open</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

This button needs to be outside the component and should open and close the picker.

For reference the actual usecase is something like as follow

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <vue-ctk-date-time-picker
      v-model="theDate"
      :name="'Date'"
      :format="'YYYY-MM-DD'"
      :formatted="'DD MMM, YYYY'"
      :only-date="true"
      :data-vv-as="'date'"
      :first-day-of-week="1"
      :no-value-to-custom-elem="false"
      :range="true"
    >
      <input type="text" /><button>Toggle</button>
    </vue-ctk-date-time-picker>
  </div>
</template>
```

The toggle button should open and close the date picker.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, @AliBahrami Just added the code and expectaions, thanks for the suggestion. Also attaching the sandbox to play around with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---**Edited**---

Add `ref="pickerRef"` to your date picker component

And modify your `<button>` as in the following code, to trigger and hide the datepicker.

```
<vue-ctk-date-time-picker
      v-model="theDate"
      ref="pickerRef"
      :name="'Date'"
      :format="'YYYY-MM-DD'"
      :formatted="'DD MMM, YYYY'"
      :only-date="true"
      :data-vv-as="'date'"
      :first-day-of-week="1"
      :range="true"
      :no-value-to-custom-elem="false"
    >
</vue-ctk-date-time-picker>
<button
    type="button"
    @click="$refs.pickerRef.toggleDatePicker(), ($refs.pickerRef.persistent = true)"
    @blur="$refs.pickerRef.persistent = false"
>
    Open
</button>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that, what it does is that it replaces the input with the button. The requirement is that the input should stay as it is and the button is placed somwhere else.

Comment: @HitendraRathore I have updated the answer, It is working in the codesandbox, please check.

Comment: @HitendraRathore answer is updated again, the Button was supposed to be outside of the <vue-ctk-date-time-picker> and is corrected now.

Comment: Thanks, got it working using a modification of the code you provided.